# Calculate the Taylor series of $\sin$ around $3$

Tags: taylor-expansion

This should be simple but I'm having trouble with it.

So by definition the series looks like

$$\sin 3 + \cos (3) (z-3) - \frac{\sin (3) (z-3)^2}{2!} - \frac{\cos (3) (z-3)^3}{3!}+...$$

To be able to write the sum I need to merge $\sin$ and $\cos$.
I observe that $\cos 3=-\sin(3+\frac{\pi}{2})$, $-\sin 3=\sin(3+\frac{2\pi}{2})$,$-\cos 3=-\sin(3+\frac{3\pi}{2})$,...

So according to the the series would look like

$$\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{\sin(3+\frac{n\pi}{2})(z-3)^n}{n!}(-1)^n$$

WolframAlpha ALMOST agrees but seems to think the $(-1)^n$ part doesn't exist.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: The successive derivatives must be taken at $z=3$, not at a variable $z$.  What you obtain is not a polynomial in $z$.

Comment: @Bernard What do you mean? Those derivatives are at $3$, just the result of that is multiplied by $(z-3)^n$

Comment: Sorry, you formula was ambiguous and I misread it. It think  it's better to write, say, $\,\dfrac{\sin 3}{3\,!} (z-3)^3$. As to your question, the $(-1)^n$ factor is already incorporated in $\,\sin(3+n\frac\pi2)$. It is well-known the $n$-derivatives of $\sin z$ and $\,\cos z$ are, respectively, $\,\sin(z+n\frac\pi2)$ and$\,\cos(z+n\frac\pi2)$.

Comment: @Bernard Yeah sorry about that. I see the mistake now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The factor of $-1$ is misplaced, because $\cos 3 \neq -\sin (3+\frac\pi2).$
Instead, $\cos 3 = \sin (3+\frac\pi2).$

Checking with a calculator (but you could also just plot it on the unit circle):

$$\cos 3 \approx -0.99.$$

$$\sin \left(3+\frac\pi2\right) \approx -0.99.$$